# Optional Binding followed by casting to an optional in swift

Tags: swift, parsing, option-type

I'm trying to parse data from a dictionary. I have code that currently works but I think there is a better more concise way to do it.

I have three options for what my dictionary can equal

```
let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["pic":"picture"] //opt1
let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["pic":2]         //opt2 
let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["pi":"this"]     //opt3
```

This is the code that I am currently using to parse the data that I would like to be improved.

```
let _pic = dictionary["pic"]
if _pic != nil && !(_pic is String) {
    print("error")
    return
}
let pic = _pic as? String
```

For each option i'd like different things to happen for:

**opt1**

```
pic:String? = Optional(picture)
```

**opt2** An error to be shown

**opt3**

```
pic:String? = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
guard let _pic = dictionary["pic"] as? String else { return }
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, the problem I had doing this was in my opt3. The thing here is I don't want there to be an error when there wasn't the right key in the dictionary.

Comment: Then you can also use if...else for that.

Comment: I have done that in the code that works. I'm looking for a improved more concise version of that (because I have to repeat this bit of code for everything I parse from the dictionary.) But if it's not possible to do a more concise version I will just keep it with what I have.

Comment: Have you done like this, 'if let _pic = dictionary[“pic”] as? String {
 // Do you code
} else {
 print(“Key not available”)
}'

Answer (score 0):

```
let _pic = dictionary["pic"]
```

This by default gives you an optional value for `_pic` that's of type `Any?`. As such, your code seems OK based on your requirements and I don't think you need the last line `let pic = _pic as? String`

Comment: I think for last option it may be crash.

Comment: Unless he now wants to use the value, in which case he'd check if the value is `!= nil` first before type-casting to `as! String`

Comment: Yeah, I might not have made that clear my aim is to then use that variable and the variable would then have to be a string?. I'll edit the question to show that.

Comment: Does an error need to be shown if the value is not string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do two tests. Here's one way:

```
guard let picAsAny = dictionary["pic"]
else { /* No key in the dictionary */ }
guard let pic = picAsAny as? String
else { /* error wrong type */ }

// pic is now a (nonoptional) string
```

Obviously you can use if statements instead of guards depending on context.